# Git branch commit, what am I doing wrong

Tags: git

I wanted to make a small change to a public git project.

So I did:

```
git clone BLAH
git checkout -b NEWBRANCH
```

made my changes to existing files and did

```
git commit -a -m "did stuff"
```

and it gives

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent )
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

Have I missed a step or something?

Comment: Are you sure you actually commit from within the git tree?

Comment: did you issue all the git commands from the same directory?

Answer (score 3):

`git clone BLAH` created a git repo in BLAH directory. Just do `cd BLAH`

Comment: Well, not quite -- the directory created will depend on the URI used. But this is the obvious answer ;)

Comment: Gahghghg, thought I had, that's fixed it.